# Can not open website hosted on LAN web server by browser, though No-IP Dynamic DNS through router OK

Tags: windows

My LAN server is using IIS ver 10.
No-IP Dynamic DNS through router with URL _.ddns.net is rightly resolving to changing external dynamic IP address supplied by internet service provider.
I can ping to URL _.ddns.net in command prompt when connected through router.
I have configured my router to assign fixed private (LAN) IP address as 192.168.1.2 and it working fine.
I have done port forwarding to my LAN web server for HTTP port 80, but don't know how to test it.
When I type URL 'localhost' OR http://192.168.1.2/ in the browser, I can see my default website. But when I type URL _.ddns.net, I see error: This site can’t be reached.

Someone told that the problem is because my LAN web server is behind the router. So I directly connected my web server pc to cable bypassing the router. But then also I get the same error when I type URL _.ddns.net OR external IP address:port in the browser.
I can not ping to URL _.ddns.net in command prompt when connected through cable.

What other settings should I do to solve this problem?

The output of Ipconfig /all is here when my pc is connect to internet by cable.
**I have noted that external IP address given by WhatsMyIp = _.ddns.net = 43.241.144.210 is not seen anywhere in Ipconfig /all listing.**

C:\Users\niranjan>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DESKTOP-HH2O346
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi
 Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-0F-02-80-03-AC
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 10:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0F-02-80-03-AC
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-27-0E-18-F0-B2
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::40c8:cb1e:2e96:30f2%6(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.48.242(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 100673294
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-25-78-61-B1-00-27-0E-18-F0-B2
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

PPP adapter GTPL BB 2:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : GTPL BB 2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.140.234.119(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 182.237.9.10
                                       8.8.8.8
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8188FTV Wireless LAN 802.11n
 USB 2.0 Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0F-02-80-03-AC
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::6941:48e4:93c5:86a0%14(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, December 29, 2019 6:37:30 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Monday, December 30, 2019 6:43:06 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 234884866
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-25-78-61-B1-00-27-0E-18-F0-B2
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Sorry for lengthy post.

Comment: Maybe you router does not support double NAT (package in>out>in)?

Answer (score 0):

assume that the setup looks like this:

```
HTTP request(internet) --> _.ddns.net --> 43.241.144.210 [router public IP][TCP/80 port forwarding] --> 192.168.1.2:80 [IIS]
```

your description shows that the most important things are configured correctly:

- `ping _.ddns.net` should return `43.241.144.210`
- services like https://www.whatismyip.com/ should return ip: `43.241.144.210`
- port forwarding on router, port TCP/80 [http] forward to `192.168.1.2:80`
- your server have ip `192.168.1.2` and default website is available form web browser: `http://192.168.1.2`

also try to check windows firewall on server - inbound rules for port 80, router firewall rules

you can also check connection by: `telnet _.ddns.net 80`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like typical problem with Hairpin NAT (to be precise lack of that in the router). You do not provided any details about that router, so I can't give you any reference to documentation or something like that.

About the direct connection of the PC with IIS to the Internet (without router) - IIUC the ethernet adapter you connect is probably `Ethernet adapter Ethernet`. If yes it is setup to obtain IP address by DHCP but there is rather a little chance that your ISP has the DHCP server setup directly (I think). I don't know who is your ISP and what technology it use but probably you need to setup some PPP connection (to authenticate themselves and then obtain IP address - this is what most of ADSL routers does).